# After saving and closing a localized Component, it remains checked out (is locked)

Tags: 2011, 5.2

When we open a Component from a child Publication, we localize it to be able to edit the Component.

[image: Seleccion]

When we finished editing, the Component is closed using the Save and Close button:

[image: Guardar y Cerrar]

After doing this, the Component sometimes remains checked out (keeps a lock icon in the list). The changed data is saved correctly, but the Component remains locked.

[image: Componente]

This only occurs sometimes, what could be the cause?

This is happening in Tridion 5.2 although catches have added 2011

Comment: I'm not sure what that last line means... "catches have added"??

Answer (score 5):

Every time you open a versioned item in CME it get's checked out.

When you click Save and Close, or close your browser window, the item automatically gets checked back in. However if the browser window closes too soon, or your browser crashes during that process (and many more reasons), the call to check the Component back in will not be sent. So your item will remain checked out (keeps the lock).

It's a bit tricky to figure out what the problem is without seeing exactly what you are doing as every little thing matters here.

Comment: I often see this happening when the UI is accessed over a slow (remote) network, my guess would be that the check-in call is received too late at the server or never fired somehow. I never have this issue when working directly on the CMS server, which seems to be an indication that network might be a cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

I forgot to say that this is happening too me in Tridion 5.2 if it could be for other reasons.

thanks

Comment: After save and close of the component, Can you check from version history, which user it is showing? Is it your id and modified date is also recent?Or it is different one which is locked from a time?

Comment: It is the same username and the date is recent

Comment: If this is what has happened, then the problem can be resolved simply by opening and closing the item again. Of course, it needs to be done by the user with the checkout.